# Fetching xml2json value to Text Widget in Flutter

Tags: json, xml, flutter, dart

I am recently working on a personal project with Flutter (which will be programmed to show all currencies on the screen with their rates) and wanting to get currency data from XML URL link and pass them to the Text Widget in my application. I use http, xml2json and convert packages from Dart library.I have two classes for this project;

connection.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Xml2Json xml2json = new Xml2Json();

class Connection {
  Future fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      xml2json.parse(response.body);
      var jsondata = xml2json.toGData();
      var data = json.decode(jsondata);
      var forexSellingUSD = data['Tarih_Date']['Currency'][0]['ForexSelling'];
      var uSD = forexSellingUSD;
      print(uSD);
      return uSD;
    }
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'connection.dart' as conn;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  conn.Connection connection = new conn.Connection();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var xyz = connection.fetchData().toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            connection.fetchData();
          },
          child: new Text('Get'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          xyz,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run my app and press the RaisedButton and the debug console outputs this 
 'I/flutter ( 7002): {$t: 6.9255}'
That is the correct number of the currency rate but this value can't be fetched to the Text Widget and it shows something like this [currency_problem_flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by61O.png) .

What should i do to fix this fetching problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  conn.Connection connection = new conn.Connection();
  String currencyVal = '';


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrencyData();
  }

   getCurrencyData()  {
    connection.fetchData().then((val){
      setState(() {
        currencyVal = val.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            getCurrencyData();
          },
          child: new Text('Get'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          currencyVal,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work for me mate, it still got the number on console but not on my screen  and also brought some bunch of errors like
 `E/flutter ( 8461): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: Updated. Just call the toString method on val in getCurrencyData method and it will show you result {$t: 6.9255} in your Text widget.

Comment: Thanks mate , it worked but how to take out the paranthesis, dollar sign and "t" around the number ? Trim function does the work ?

Comment: You should be creating a Model of every data you receive from the api to parse it . That way you won't have to do redundant work and perform complicated functions. Here is an official guide to follow : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json